# How do I run a simple text-based Java program as an app in Windows?

Tags: java, console, exe

I'm doing an online Java course through my university. I have just finished an assignment in IntelliJ. It's a very basic text-based game that prints information to the console using `System.out.println`, as well as taking keyboard inputs from the user.

The game consists of several classes, an interface, an abstract class, and the main program [screen shot of structure here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ADik.png).

Although not part of the assignment, I am curious as to what I would need to do so this "game" could be run outside of IntelliJ as a .exe (or similar) in Windows directly. For example, if a friend wanted to play on their PC without having IntelliJ installed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I convert my Java program to an .exe file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/147181/how-can-i-convert-my-java-program-to-an-exe-file)

Answer (score 0):

This seems quite similar to the following [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/147181/how-can-i-convert-my-java-program-to-an-exe-file)
Long story short: there are quite a few ways to realise that. So i think, that you need to find that out for yourself. For me the [javapackager](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/tools/javapackager.htm#JSWOR719) was enough and worked fine for my cases.